# custom dask graphs with functions that need dask computed keyword arguments

Tags: python, dask

How can one construct a custom dask graph using a function that requires keyword arguments that are the result of another dask task?

The dask documentation and several stackoverflow questions suggest using `partial`, `toolz`, or `dask.compatibility.apply`. All of these solutions work for static keyword arguments. My understanding from from [Including keyword arguments (kwargs) in custom Dask graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861900/including-keyword-arguments-kwargs-in-custom-dask-graphs) and some reading of the source code and debugger is that `dask.compatibility.apply` might be able to work with keyword arguments that are the result of a dask computation. However, I can't seem to get the syntax right nor can I find the answer elsewhere.

The example below shows a relatively simple application of `dask.compatibility.apply` with a dask computed keyword value. Dask successfully passes the values of the computed args `'a'` and `'b'`, as well as the static keyword value `'other'`. However, it passes the string `'c'` to the function rather than replacing it with its computed value.

```
import dask
from dask.compatibility import apply


def custom_func(a, b, other=None, c=None):
    print(a, b, other, c)
    return a * b / c / other


dsk = {
    'a': (sum, (1, 1)),
    'b': (sum, (2, 2)),
    'c': (sum, (3, 3)),
    'd': (apply, custom_func, ['a', 'b'], {'c': 'c', 'other': 2})
}

dask.visualize(dsk, filename='graph.png')
for key in sorted(dsk):
    print(key)
    print(dask.get(dsk, key))
    print('\n')
```

The output is below:

```
a
2


b
4


c
6


d
2 4 2 c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dask_kwarg.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(dask.get(dsk, key))
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 562, in get_sync
    return get_async(apply_sync, 1, dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 529, in get_async
    fire_task()
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 504, in fire_task
    callback=queue.put)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 551, in apply_sync
    res = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 295, in execute_task
    result = pack_exception(e, dumps)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 290, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 271, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/Users/holmgren/miniconda3/envs/pvlib36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 50, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "dask_kwarg.py", line 7, in custom_func
    return a * b / c / other
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

[image: graph.png]

Comment: This seems specific enough that it could be considered a bug - either this is supposed to work, the documentation is unclear, or it's a feature that should be requested. I suggest you re-post to github.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3741

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to find out how dask.delayed does it :)

```
In [1]: import dask

In [2]: @dask.delayed
   ...: def f(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: dict(f(x=1).dask)
Out[3]: 
{'f-d2cd50e7-25b1-49c5-b463-f05198b09dfb': (<function dask.compatibility.apply>,
  <function __main__.f>,
  [],
  (dict, [['x', 1]]))}
```

Interestingly this is also a case where the local scheduler and distributed scheduler disagree.  The distributed scheduler handles this fine.

```
In [1]: from dask.distributed import Client

In [2]: client = Client()

In [3]: import dask
   ...: from dask.compatibility import apply
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def custom_func(a, b, other=None, c=None):
   ...:     print(a, b, other, c)
   ...:     return a * b / c / other
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: dsk = {
   ...:     'a': (sum, (1, 1)),
   ...:     'b': (sum, (2, 2)),
   ...:     'c': (sum, (3, 3)),
   ...:     'd': (apply, custom_func, ['a', 'b'], {'c': 'c', 'other': 2})
   ...: }
   ...: 

In [4]: for key in sorted(dsk):
   ...:     print(key, client.get(dsk, key))
   ...:     
a 2
b 4
c 6
2 4 2 6
d 0.6666666666666666
```